# Any character other than

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex, sedlex

I have defined a token for ocamllex `let non_line_termination_character = [^ '\x0D' '\x0A']`, which represents any character other than `'\x0D'` and `'\x0A'`.

Now, I would like to translate it to sedlex.

Does anyone know how to translate it correctly? Should I use `SUB` (e.g., `SUB(SUB(any, '\x0D'), '\x0A')` or `SUB(any, ('\x0D' | '\x0A'))`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This corresponds to `Compl` as described in sedlex documentation

```
Compl  ('\x0D' | '\x0A')
```

See also the example at https://github.com/ocaml-community/sedlex/blob/master/examples/complement.ml .